# Why render settings are not related to the active camera?

Tags: rendering, camera

I am doing some interior design rendering and I have multiple cameras in the sceen to show different details, and I also have a few panoramic cameras (equirectangular) to show the entire room.
I find annoing that when I switch the active camera, I need to manually tweek the render settings to match the selected camera (2/1 for equirectangular, 16/9 or 4/3 for still, ecc.).
I believe that the settings like dimensions, resolution, sampling (and so on) settings should be tied to the camera in order to have the possibility to have cameras dedicated to different needs (low res, high res, panoramic ...)
Do you know why it is not working like this?
And do you know if there is an addon that can do that for me?
(otherwise I may write one... ;)

Thanks.
Regards.
Mau.

Comment: Please *do* write one :)

Comment: I think the phyilosophy of having these settings tied to the scene rather than the camera is to use different scenes (which can be linked) for each of these different camera settings. Seems a bit cumbersome though

Comment: Yes the settings are tied to the scene and you can link them. But anyway the two or more scenes will share all objects even newly created ones.
If you have 10 cameras you will end up with 10 identical scenes with 10 cameras in each.
True that you can have only the right camera active and visible in each scene and hide the others, but if you happen to switch camera in one scene you screw up anything.
So you need to keep everything in sync manually
But anyway, short of writing a specific addon this is the closest solution to my need